# Creating a dynamic image upload PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yoxview

I am wanting to allow a user to upload images dynamically and display them in some sort of reasonable view. I am not picky how it looks, just that it's functional. I stumbled onto YoxView and have been trying to use it. I followed the installation here: http://www.yoxigen.com/yoxview/usage.aspx#installation

However, I can't seem to get it to work properly. The images aren't uploading dynamically and they once the page is refreshed they are displaying the thumbnails, however, the thumbnails are the size of the uploaded image, not what I am telling them to resize to. (My thumbnails are being created in a folder `unit_images/thumbnails`.

Furthermore, the CSS for the YoxView isn't getting displayed.

Here is where the images are displayed on the page `unit_edit.php`

```
<div class="editunitimages">
        <form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='upload.php?id=<?php print $_GET['id']; ?>' >
            Upload image <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
        </form>

        <div id='preview'>
        </div>
        <div id="unit_images">
            <?php
                require_once('config/db.php');
                $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
                $query = "SELECT id, image FROM images WHERE unit = ".$_GET['id']."";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                echo '<div class="yoxview">';
                $i = 1;
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    echo '<a href="unit_images/'.$row['image'].'"><img src="unit_images/thumbnails/'.$row['image'].'" alt="'.$i.'" title="image '.$i.'" /></a>';
                    $i++;
                }
                echo '</div>';
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>  <!-- end editunitimages -->
```

I also have a style on the page for it

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yoxview/yoxview-init.js"></script>
<style>
    .preview{width:200px;border:solid 1px #dedede;padding:10px;}
    #preview{color:#cc0000;font-size:12px}
</style>
```

This is the JS i have for it on the same page

*Here I am getting a console error that says* `Uncaught Reference Error: options is not defined`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#thumbnails").yoxview([options]);
    $('#photoimg').live('change', function()    
    { 

        $("#preview").html('');
        $("#preview").html('<img src="images/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
            target: '#preview'
        }).submit();
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Here is my `upload.php` file

*I notice that the `print_r('here');` is not displaying on the page, either. Which I assume is why my image thumbnails aren't being resized (they remain the same as the upload size)*

```
  <?php
function resize_image($file, $w, $h, $crop=FALSE) {
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
$r = $width / $height;
if ($crop) {
    print_r('here');
    if ($width > $height) {
        $width = ceil($width-($width*abs($r-$w/$h)));
    } else {
        $height = ceil($height-($height*abs($r-$w/$h)));
    }
    $newwidth = $w;
    $newheight = $h;
} else {
    if ($w/$h > $r) {
        $newwidth = $h*$r;
        $newheight = $h;
    } else {
        $newheight = $w/$r;
        $newwidth = $w;
    }
}
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

return $dst;
}

require_once('config/db.php');
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$query = "SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM images";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 { $image_id = $row['id']; $image_id++; }

$path = "unit_images/";

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "jpeg");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        $name = strtolower($_FILES['photoimg']['name']);
        $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

        if(strlen($name))
            {
                list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                {
                if($size<((1024*1024)*5))
                    {
                        $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
                        $actual_image_name = $image_id.'_'.$actual_image_name;
                        $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                            {
                                $file = $path.$actual_image_name;
                                $thumb = $path.'/thumbnails/'.$actual_image_name;
                                if (!copy($file, $thumb)) { echo 'Failed to copy.'; }
                                resize_image($thumb, 60, 40);

                                $query = "INSERT INTO images(unit, image) VALUES(".$_GET['id'].",'".$actual_image_name."')";
                                mysqli_query($con,$query);
                                //echo "<img src='unit_images/".$thumb."'  class='preview'>";
                            }
                        else
                            echo "failed";
                    }
                    else
                    echo "Image file size max 1 MB";                    
                    }
                    else
                    echo "Invalid file format..";   
            }

        else
            echo "Please select image..!";

        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your sql is open to sql injection, `?id=1 or 1=1` use parameterized querys instead

Comment: You're right. I just haven't went back to do that yet.

Comment: injection defense isn't something you get around to "later". You either do it from the very beginning, or you stop programming.

Comment: If it isn't live, what's the worry? Also, this is isn't pertinent to my question. This is aback end system that only a few people will have access to anyway.

Comment: Have you got the GD image library loaded in PHP?

Comment: Oh well, I'd better stop programming.  As nice an idea (and to which I do have some sympathy), it is much easier (in my experience) to get a working, private, prototype to keep superiors happy, and *then* explain that I need to spend time making it secure.  Non-technical people, who I often work for, want *visible* results 1st, and only then are willing to accept full scale production code takes longer to produce

Comment: @AdRock No, I did a quick Google and looks like an add on to PHP? I will look into how to install it. Any additional tips on install of GD?

Comment: If you look in the PHP directory under EXT you should see a file called php_gd2.dll.  If it's there, go to php.ini and uncomment that extension and restart apache

Comment: @AdRock I had both, actually. The file is there and uncommented in `.ini`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this can help you but this works for me.  I create a thumbnail version and a larger version of the image i'm uploading then move them into their respective directories

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
    $twidth = "100";   // Maximum Width For Thumbnail Images 
    $theight = "75";   // Maximum Height For Thumbnail Images 
    $lwidth = "500";   // Maximum Width For Thumbnail Images 
    $lheight = "375";   // Maximum Height For Thumbnail Images

    $picture = $_FILES['imagefile']['name'];   // Set $url To Equal The Filename For Later Use 

    if ($_FILES['imagefile']['type'] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES['imagefile']['type'] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES['imagefile']['type'] == "image/pjpeg") { 
        $imagename = $_FILES['imagefile']['name'];
        $source = $_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'];

        $target = "/www/mvc/public/uploads/".$imagename;

        if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target)) {

            $imagepath = $imagename;

            $save = "/www/mvc/public/images/content/" . $imagename; //This is the new file you saving
            $file = "/www/mvc/public/uploads/" . $imagepath; //This is the original file

            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ; 

            $currwidth = imagesx($image);   // Current Image Width 
            $currheight = imagesy($image);   // Current Image Height 
            if ($currheight > $currwidth) {   // If Height Is Greater Than Width 
                $zoom = $lwidth / $currheight;   // Length Ratio For Width 
                $newheight = $lheight;   // Height Is Equal To Max Height 
                $newwidth = $currwidth * $zoom;   // Creates The New Width 
            } else {    // Otherwise, Assume Width Is Greater Than Height (Will Produce Same Result If Width Is Equal To Height) 
                $zoom = $lwidth / $currwidth;   // Length Ratio For Height 
                $newwidth = $lwidth;   // Width Is Equal To Max Width 
                $newheight = $currheight * $zoom;   // Creates The New Height 
            }

            $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight) ; 
            imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $currwidth, $currheight) ; 

            imagejpeg($tn, $save, 100) ; 

            imagedestroy($image);

            unlink($target);

            //echo '<p style="margin: 0 auto;"><img id="previmg" src="/admin/resized/'.$imagename.'" alt="'.$imagename.'" title="'.$imagename.'" /></p>';
        }
        else {
            echo "Error moving file!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. See my [new post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134829/dynamic-image-upload-with-thumbnail-view)